# A standard global variable in the params for a module is not being parsed

Tags: module, global-variables, parameters

I have a module tag with a param that accepts a string.

```
{exp:test:foo return_url="{current_url}"}
...
{/exp:test:foo}
```

In the module method, I get the return_url param using

```
$return_url      = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('return_url');
```

The problem is that I get the literal string

`{current_url}`

As opposed to it being parsed and [getting the current url](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/single_variables.html#current-url).

Is there a way to solve this? or is this a parse order issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is parse order. Read the attached pdf.[parse order](http://loweblog.com/downloads/ee-parse-order.pdf).
Turn on the debugger and then view the template in your browser. Scroll down thru the debugger until you find the tag containing {current_url}. You will see that that {current_url} has not been parsed. According to the attached doc, it is not parsed until step 9 - last.

In your module, try

`$uri_string = $this->EE->input->server('PATH_INFO') !== FALSE ? $this->EE->input->server('PATH_INFO') : '/'.$this->EE->uri->uri_string();`

or

`$segments       = array_values($this->EE->uri->segment_array());`

or

`$this->EE->functions->fetch_current_uri()`

Comment: Hmm could assigning it to preload variables work?

Comment: If not, is there an alternative way to get the current url?

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: Your solution are good. I added the solution that I used that worked for me.